# Unable to remove text-decoration for phone number in iOS webview

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, titanium

I am unable to remove the text-decoration in this sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
     p.p1 {
        margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px;
        font: 14.0px Arial;
        text-decoration:none
     }
</style>

<p class="p1" style="text-decoration: none">
       For emergencies, please contact `1-234-567-1234` immediately.
       <span class="Apple-converted-space">
       </span>
</p>
```

I am loading `WebView` the html page its still loading 1-234-567-1234 with underline link blue color in `WebView` titanium.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a HTML or CSS issue, that's the iOS native webbrowser recognizing a phone number and giving it an internal link so you can use it to call or look up contacts. Since it doesn't exist in the DOM, there's nothing you can do to remove or style it with standard CSS.

There's a crappy workaround from Apple, [documented here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/keep-iphone-browser-from-turning-numbers-into-links):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Put it in your `<head>` and it's supposed to stop the phone number highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<p class="p1" style="text-decoration:none !important;" >
```

Comment: really? well it does for other text. It was not mentioned in the question that the problem is for numbers. Even an animal knows that numbers are viewed in blue :/

Comment: The [original unedited question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16812332/1) already clearly stated that only the phone number was affected.